# template driven form resetting

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using template driven form in my project and I want to reset the form values after form submission. both reset and resetForm methods are not working here is the code

***Component.html***

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="close(form)">
  <input type="number" ngModel name ="RevenueSale" 
  [(ngModel)]="closingRegister.RevenueSale" class=" theme-input" 
  placeholder="0.00">

  <input type="number" ngModel name ="TaxCollected" 
  [(ngModel)]="closingRegister.TaxCollected" class=" theme-input" 
  placeholder="0.00">

  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
    <button (click) = "modal.close()" type="button" class="btn btn-outline- 
     secondary mr-4">CANCEL</button> 
    <button type="submit"class="btn theme-btn">CLOSE</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

***Component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Register } from '@app/core/models/register/register';

import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
@Component({
templateUrl: './compoment.component.html', 
})
 export class myComponent implements OnInit, {
 closingRegister = <Register>{};
 constructor(private router: Router,
 private registerSerive: RegisterService,
 private toastr: ToastrService,
 )  {}

 ngOnInit(){

  }

 close(form: NgForm){

  //this.registerSerive.closeRegister(this.closingRegister).subscribe( 
    closedRegister => {
    this.toastr.success('Register closed');
    this.modalService.dismissAll();
    console.log(form.value);
    form.reset();  
   //}
   }  
}
```

Comment: Where is you submit button?

Comment: my bad, please check again

Comment: I have tried to create this in stackblitz. It's working, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tempalte-driven-subkit-stack

Comment: here closing register is an array of register object
  closingRegister = new Register();

Comment: how can I debug this?

Comment: If it's array you should use ngFor to loop the data to bind the value to model

Comment: closingRegister = <Register>{} ;

Comment: Can you add some more code

Comment: please check again

Comment: does console inside close method is getting printed or not?

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the wrong form. Try

`ngForm.reset();`

Comment: how can I call this?

Comment: in close function.